# how to configure tax settings for usa only store?

Tags: magento-1.9.2.1, taxes

when a shop is sending items from New York and only sells in the USA, do i still need to configure all different taxes for every state? Or just the state where items will be shipped from? Is there a csv available to import that contains all necessary settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure all different taxes from admin `sales->Tax->Manage Tax Zones & Rates` for different state

You can import csv from `sales->Tax->Import / Export Tax Rates`

please refer http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/export-and-import-tax-rates

Comment: hi thanks, but this is not an answer to the question. what i wanted to know was if i have to charge New York tax for all states or a state depending tax rate... and secondly if there is a file available somewhere to import ;-)

Comment: Simply add country code postcode of state and tax rate in csv and import it.please refer given link.

Comment: @PrashantValanda How to include TAX while creating manual order?

Comment: @zus while creating manual order from admin it will automatically calculate tax according to your shipping address

Comment: @PrashantValanda How to get TAX value for appropriate product in PHP page?